# Jasper - conflito de versões

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Bom dia! Pessoal, estou tendo problemas ao tentar alterar um relatório de uma aplicação. Esse relatório em pdf foi criado na versão 6.2.0 e mesmo utilizando a versão 6.2.0.final não consigo gerar o arquivo .jasper por conflito de versões. Não posso atualizar na aplicação para uma versão mais recente porque há outros relatórios de outras equipes na mesma aplicação. Já tentei com várias outras versões do jaspersoft e em todos tenho o mesmo problema, mesmo alterando a versão na opção de gerar o .jasper. Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Rodrigo, você pode incluir mais informações, como mensagem de erro, print do que foi feito, entre outras coisas. Assim os usuários terão mais facilidade pra te ajudar

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Amigo parece que ele nao encontra o .class da sua entidade , adiciona o classpath das classes compiladas para que ele possa fazer a leitura dos beans ?, afinal ClassNotFound é uma excessao causada por nao encontrar a classe ItemPedidoPDF

Comment: Obrigado Denis, vou fazer isso aqui e retorno se funcionou